# Не с прилагательными в краткой форме

Tags: частица-не

Подзабыла правило: "цели неясны", но"цели пока не ясны" - или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, утверждаете ли вы отрицательный признак (тогда слитно) или отрицаете положительный (тогда раздельно). Это общий принцип правописания НЕ с чем бы то ни было, он очень помогает не запутаться в многочисленных правилах и избавляет от зубрежки. Собственно, все правила и следуют из этого принципа.

В обоих ваших примерах возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание. Многое зависит от контекста.

Нужно также смотреть, есть ли вообще слово с НЕ в языке. Например, слово *неширок*, безусловно, есть, а вот *неузок* нету.

Comment: Так! Тогда, следуя этому общему принципу, - "не узок и не широк, не низок и не глубок" - верно?

Comment: Да, верно.

Answer (score 2):

"Не" с краткими прилагательными пишется по тем же правилам, что и с полными. У прилагательных зависимые слова не влияют на слитное или раздельное написание.
Следовательно, "цели пока неясны".

Comment: А эти... предикативы? Они ведь внешне очень похожи на краткие прилагательные. Прям до неотличимости. Или вот, допустим, причастия: как их по внешнему виду отличить от кратких прилагательных - какая-нибудь там _(давно) (не)крашеная скамейка_?

Да и зависимые слова иногда попадаются очень противные: __цели _отнюдь_ не ясны__.

http://static.ir2.ru/ru/pravila2.htm#p89

Comment: Да. Но:
1. Вопрос поставлен так: "Не с прилагательными в краткой форме". Стало быть, часть речи уже определена.
2. Зависимое слово тоже дано вполне конкретное и простое, как валенок.
Поэтому если считать, что цель вопроса не теоретические изыскания, а руководство к действию в спорном случае, то и мой ответ сгодится.

Comment: Если отбросить мою риторику (типа "всё сложно"), то останется простое (как валенок) отрицание вашего тезиса. 

У прилагательных зависим__ые__ слов__а__ таки __влияют__. (Обобщение неправомерное).